# Biblioteca para criação de gráficos VueJS?

Tags: javascript, front-end, vue.js, gráfico

Estou precisando fazer a geração de gráficos, e estou usando o framework VueJS, juntamente com o Quasar. Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe ou conhece alguma biblioteca para que eu possa gerar esses gráficos; Já vi algumas, mas a documentação está em chinês, o que dificulta bastante. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Já vistou a lojinha do Vue? https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#charts

Comment: você pode usar o [Vue Charts](http://vue-chartjs.org)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, vou dar uma olhada e ver qual se adapta melhor ao que preciso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Vue-Chartjs](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs), é bem simples de usar, alem de ser um dos mais bonitos.

```
import VueCharts from 'vue-chartjs'    
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'GitHub Commits',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Sim, já teste ela e consegui implementar tudo certinho...